# Count number of times that each API version shows up in log file

Tags: shell-script, shell

Develop script which receives data from localhost on port 33001 and finds how many times distinct API version is requested and print it on a screen.

Sample log is:

```
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/2.3
98.134.54.184 182294 /api/2.3
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/2.3/security
203.44.122.18 397832 /api/3.0
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/2.3
98.134.54.184 182294 /api/3.0
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/2.3/logging
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/2.3
71.11.139.205 291187 /api/2.3
172.32.11.121 736443 /api/3.0/security
98.134.54.184 182294 /api/2.3
71.11.139.205 397832 /api/3.0/logging
```

First field is IP-address, second one is user id and last one is path to resource.

Comment: 1) format your question; 2) post the expected result

Comment: Starting a question with "Develop a script ...." sounds a lot like an instruction to underlings.  Develop it yourself.

Comment: I disagree with @cas, it sounds like homework, and one you don't want to do.

Comment: @Archemar It really doesn't matter if it's homework or not - he posted his question as if he's entitled to be giving instructions here.  If that's the direct text of a homework question he should have re-written it or at least prefaced it with an intro so that it wasn't so demanding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a demand to do his work for him.

Comment: @cas sorry,  the "you" in my sentence was misleading, it was rather "that the OP don't want to do". English is not my mother tongue, I've only been trying to speak it for a mere forty years.

Comment: @Archemar yeah, i got that. in fact i not only assumed that was what you meant, it never even occurred to me that you might have meant me or anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you care only about the version and not the whole path:

```
$ awk -F/ '{count[$3]++} END {for (v in count) print v, count[v]}' file
2.3 8
3.0 4
```

Splitting fields on `/`, the version number seems to be the third field in all lines.

Comment: Additionally, find users who made requests from more than one unique IP-address and print on screen.
Expected output is:
(397832,2)

Comment: for this can you just help me to read the data instead of just put the file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data in file `indata`:

```
$ awk '{ ++c[$NF] } END { for (i in c) print c[i], i }' indata
1 /api/2.3/logging
1 /api/3.0/security
6 /api/2.3
2 /api/3.0
1 /api/3.0/logging
1 /api/2.3/security
```

The `awk` script keeps track of the number of times the data in the last column has shown up and prints a summary of this information at the end.

To only get the version *number*, use `-F '/'` and replace `$NF` with `$3`.

Alternatively:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 3 indata | sort | uniq -c
   6 /api/2.3
   1 /api/2.3/logging
   1 /api/2.3/security
   2 /api/3.0
   1 /api/3.0/logging
   1 /api/3.0/security
```

This cuts out the third space-separate column from the data and sorts it. `uniq -c` then counts how many times each unique entry occurs.

To only get the version number with this variation, replace `-d ' '` with `-d '/'` in the call to `cut`.

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, find users who made requests from more than one unique IP-address and print on screen.
Expected output is:
(397832,2)

Comment: @mathivannan Update the text of the question rather than adding details in comments. Answers must always be related to the question.

Comment: How to get the data in run time?

Comment: @mathivannan Please edit your question. (and describe there what you mean by "in run time").